# Ways with certain number of Nodes

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api, overpass-turbo

Need an overpass-turbo query to highlight on a map [highways] in a certain city with a certain number of nodes. Tried something like

```
[out:json];
area[name="New York City"]->.ny;
way(area.ny)[highway];
foreach (
  way._(if:count(nodes) == 50);
  out geom;
);
```

but it returned an empty set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me some time to dig through the documentation but the key to solve your question is the `count_members()` [evaluator](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_QL#Element_Properties_Count). I've changed your query to the following:

```
[out:json];
area[name="New York"]->.ny;
way(area.ny)["highway"];
foreach (
  way._(if:count_members() == 50);
  out geom;
);
```

Instead of the `count(nodes)` evaluator (which will count the `nodes` in the set and you have only `ways` in it) you need to count the members of the `ways` which you can correctly compare then. Here is my result:

[image: The result of the above query.]

And here is some more detailed view to show that the ways are added correctly and not only seen as circles:

[image: More detailed view to see the ways correctly.]